# android ringing vibration activate/deactivate

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, vibration

I can't find a way I can activate and deactivate the vibration at the time of incoming calls.

The option in the menu --> Settings --> Sounds & Display mentions - PHONE VIBRATE - vibrate phone for incoming calls...

I want to activate and deactivate it through code (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look AudioManager:

http://d.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

and setRingerMode/setVibrateSetting:

http://d.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode(int)

http://d.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setVibrateSetting(int, int)

Comment: wow!!! i thought it must b somewhere in other classes... thanx for the proper guidance... and sorry for behaving ratherly stupidly...

Comment: The only issue I see here is that RINGER_MODE_NORMAL can mean that the phone may be audible and may vibrate. Is there a way to know for sure whether or not the phone vibrate setting is on (other than using deprecated methods)?